# Customize update_last_login in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-users, django-2.2

This is django `update_last_login`:

```
#django.contrib.auth
def update_last_login(sender, user, **kwargs):
        """
        A signal receiver which updates the last_login date for
        the user logging in.
        """
        user.last_login = timezone.now()
        user.save(update_fields=['last_login'])
```

**I want to change timezone of `update_last_login` signal and customize it**. *How can I do this ?*

Comment: Make sure to read about Django's [timezone support](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/), which makes this almost surely the wrong thing to do. If you have `USE_TZ = True` all timezones will be stored as UTC, regardless of what you do. If you're doing this because you want it to display a certain way, there are other, better ways of achieving that described in the documentation.

Comment: I want to use `django-jalali` to set my `Datetime`. So I want to change `timezone.now()` by default of `django-jalali`. @KevinChristopherHenry